# Thin plate regression splines: weighted version, risk of oversmoothing?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, weighted-regression

Is any specific caution needed when using thin plate regression splines with weights? Is there possible "interaction" between penalization of curvature and weighted likelihood, potentially leading to oversmoothing? Is there automatic effective cross-validation within mgcv that chooses the optimal smoothing parameter?

Comment: Supplementary issue: is it possible to allow for different smoothing parameter for different "by=" variable leveles, or this is what actually is going by default.